# Ribbed effect to solid shapes

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, displacement, 3d-printing

I just started with blender and can't fix this problem.
Because I would like to create a ribbed effect on different shapes.

I have tried several things with the Displace Modifyer but without success. I have attached a picture to give an idea of what I would like to achieve. I would like to apply the effect to solide shapes.

I would prefer to leave the bottom of the shapes flat.

[image: Ribbed shaped]

Comment: This is a duplicate... But I don't remember which post.

Comment: That one did really help me. Only the texture get weird at the top point where the ribbed part comes together. (If that makes sense.) For example I would like the bottom part just to be flat.